# JCombobox arrow disappears

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

When the fill combobox in a method which is not placed in the constructor, the arrow of combobox disappears.

I tried with the invokeLater method, but it did not work.

[image]

```
private void fillProduct(){
    this.VALID_FOR_PRODUCT.removeAllItems();
    this.VALID_FOR_PRODUCT.addItem(new JChooseItem("ALL", "Any"));
    for(Product product : Product.values()){
        this.VALID_FOR_PRODUCT.addItem(new JChooseItem(product.getName(), langHelper.getTrans(product.getTranslationKey())));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the code part, you've posted, give us no hint about the cause of your problem. Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your problem.

Comment: Variable names should NOT be all upper cased. Upper cased names are used for "final static". A combo box should not be static. They should follow the same pattern as your method names. Only upper case the first letter of each addition descriptive word in the variable name.

Comment: @camickr True, but probably not the reason an icon disappears...

Comment: @Robert, which is why a comment was used, not an answer. The point is if somebody asks a question and they want people to take the time to read/answer the question, then the code in the question should be properly coded to make it easy to read. Part of the forum highlighting is based on proper Java naming conventions.

Comment: We are getting the components from the XUL document, and that is why they are written in uppercase letters, and the variables are declared in Java is in lowercase. @camickr you are right we know this. I still did not find the reason why the arrow disappears if I fill it with a method that is not in the constructor. I need to fill it from the out of constructor because every selected item in the table has a different data in the combo box.

Comment: `I still did not find the reason why the arrow disappears` - and you still haven't posted an [mcve]. Adding data to the model does not affect the painting of the arrow. Even an empty combo box will paint an arrow.You must have other code that is removing the button from the combo box. I have no idea what an XUL document is, but that would likely be where your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, it happened when I used method `removeAllComponents()` method instead of `removeAll()` method