# Populating JComboBox in PopupMenuListener causes arrow button to disappear

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I need to populate a `JComboBox` when the user clicks on it, because it is populated from a database which can change, and the user specifically requested this functionality.

That part works fine, but after the list populates the down arrow button disappears.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
myComboBox.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener(){
   @Override
   public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e){
      JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
      comboBox.removeAll();
      for(String value : DbClass.retrieveValues()){
         comboBox.addItem(value);
      }
   }
}
```

I also tried getting the model of the `JComboBox` and calling `removeAllElements()` instead of using `removeAll()` on the `JComboBox` itself.  The result was the same, with the down arrow button disappearing.

The following already-answered question does not address my problem, because the proposed solution does not work in this case:
[JCombobox arrow disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949890/jcombobox-arrow-disappears)

Comment: You should use ``removeAllItems()`` instead of ``removeAll()``. The first one is for your items, the latter one is for the subcomponents, among them the arrow.

Comment: `removeAllItems()` worked.  The cited question above said to do the opposite, I'm sorry I should have tried that